# (org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException) org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm starting to learn about hibernate for a development of a web system in Java, but I'm having some problems mapping and use of classes.

I have two tables: tblusuario and tblperfilusuario, tblusuario makes foreign key with tblperfilusuario, ie, a user conté a profile.

Using the Postgres database + Netbeans and Hibernate 4.3.1

TblUsuario entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "tblusuario", schema = "public")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "codigousuario"))
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_sequence",
        sequenceName = "tblusuario_codigousuario_seq",
        allocationSize = 1)
public class TblUsuario extends BaseEntityInt {

    private TblPerfilUsuario tblperfilusuario;
    private String nome;
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;

    public TblUsuario() {
    }

    public TblUsuario(String nome, String usuario, String senha) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public TblUsuario(TblPerfilUsuario tblperfilusuario, String nome, String usuario, String senha) {
        this.tblperfilusuario = tblperfilusuario;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigoperfilusuario")
    public TblPerfilUsuario getTblperfilusuario() {
        return this.tblperfilusuario;
    }

    public void setTblperfilusuario(TblPerfilUsuario tblperfilusuario) {
        this.tblperfilusuario = tblperfilusuario;
    }

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Column(name = "usuario", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getUsuario() {
        return this.usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    @Column(name = "senha", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getSenha() {
        return this.senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```

TblPerfilUsuario entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "tblperfilusuario", schema = "public")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "codigoperfilusuario"))
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_sequence",
        sequenceName = "tblperfilusuario_codigoperfilusuario_seq",
        allocationSize = 1)
public class TblPerfilUsuario extends BaseEntityInt {

    private String nome;
    private boolean ativo;
    private Set<TblUsuario> tblusuarios = new HashSet(0);

    public TblPerfilUsuario() {
    }

    public TblPerfilUsuario(String nome, boolean ativo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }

    public TblPerfilUsuario(String nome, boolean ativo, Set<TblUsuario> tblusuarios) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.ativo = ativo;
        this.tblusuarios = tblusuarios;
    }

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Column(name = "ativo", nullable = false)
    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return this.ativo;
    }

    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblperfilusuario")
    public Set<TblUsuario> getTblusuarios() {
        return this.tblusuarios;
    }

    public void setTblusuarios(Set<TblUsuario> tblusuarios) {
        this.tblusuarios = tblusuarios;
    }

}
```

Every time I try to use **TblUsuario.tblperfilusuario.getNome()** got the following error:

> e = (org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException) org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the annotation @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) to @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) in class TblUsuario.

Ex:

`public class TblUsuario extends BaseEntityInt {
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigoperfilusuario")
    public TblPerfilUsuario getTblperfilusuario() {
        return this.tblperfilusuario;
    }
...`